# Raspbian: static IP for eth0 and dhcp for wlan0

Tags: wifi, raspbian-stretch, dhcp, wpa

I run a Raspberry Pi at our university (Raspbian Stretch). I use it for a project where it has to rely on WiFi. I configured the connection using wpa_supplicant and it worked perfectly well. Now there's a problem with it, so I no longer get onto it using WiFi/ssh. I unplugged the SD card and modified `/etc/network/interfaces` file to configure a static network that allows me to acces the Raspi over Ethernet. Here's the file:

```
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.66.101
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.66.100
```

The Ethernet connection works perfectly, so I can acces my Raspi via ssh again. When I do `/etc/init.d/neworking restart`, it takes a while, but I don't get a WiFi connection. When i run `sudo systemctl restart dhcpcd.service`, it fails. `systemctl status dhcpcd.service` says:

```
Feb 23 09:33:01 pren7 systemd[1]: Starting dhcpcd on all interfaces...
Feb 23 09:33:01 pren7 dhcpcd[3065]: Not running dhcpcd because /etc/network/interfaces
Feb 23 09:33:01 pren7 dhcpcd[3065]: defines some interfaces that will use a
Feb 23 09:33:01 pren7 dhcpcd[3065]: DHCP client or static address
Feb 23 09:33:01 pren7 systemd[1]: dhcpcd.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=6
Feb 23 09:33:01 pren7 systemd[1]: Failed to start dhcpcd on all interfaces.
Feb 23 09:33:01 pren7 systemd[1]: dhcpcd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 23 09:33:01 pren7 systemd[1]: dhcpcd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

So can't I use DHCP for wlan0 when I configure eth0 using a static IP? Is there a workaround? I cannot just deactivate eth0, because if the wlan0 connection fails, I need to modify the config directly on the SD card again.

EDIT: Following your suggestion, I switched from classic networking to dhcpcd. Here's my new `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

And here's my `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`:

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.66.101/24
static routers=192.168.66.100
static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8
```

Answer (score 2):

Now I figured it out, thanks for the link!

## Raspi Setup

After copying image to SD card:

```
mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt # mount boot partition
touch /mnt/ssh # activates ssh
umount /mnt

mount /dev/mmcblk0p2 /mnt # mount root partition
```

Edit `/mnt/etc/dhcpcd.conf`:

```
# static ethernet interface for debugging
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.66.101/24
static routers=192.168.66.100
static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8
```

Umount SD card:

```
umount /mnt
```

Remove SD card, plug it into the Raspberry.

On Arch Linux, set up the Ethernet as follows:

```
sudo ip link set enp0s31f6 up
sudo ip addr add 192.168.66.100/24 broadcast 192.168.66.255 dev enp0s31f6
```

Connect to Raspberry using ssh:

```
ssh pi@192.168.66.101 # default password: raspberry
```

Add WiFi credentials:

```
wpa_passphrase [essid] [passphrase] >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Enable `wpa_supplicant`:

```
systemctl enable wpa_supplicant.service
systemctl start wpa_supplicant.service
```

Restart networking:

```
systemctl restart dhcpcd.service
```

Answer (score 1):

You can continue to use obsolete Debian networking despite its limitations - it normally configures a single interface (your implementation is non-standard and it is anyone's guess what it would do).

Including `dhcp` in `/etc/network/interface` causes `dhcpcd` to disable itself.

However I suggest you use the recommended normal `dhcpcd` networking.

See [How to set up networking/WiFi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Comment: I now tried to switch to dhcpcd. Can I use dhcp in `iface wlan0 inet dhcp` as i did (see my edit above).

Comment: You haven't specified what OS you are using. The link specifies the correct settings for both Jessie/Stretch. `/etc/network/interface` is an anachronism - the default setting effectively does **nothing** - if you delete it networking continues. The only limitation is `dhcpcd` detects if `dhcp` is used and disables itself (as the logs will show).

Comment: I have, see the first line of my post.

Comment: @PatrickBucher You should indicate OS in a tag, rather than expecting people to search your post. `Raspbian` is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add line below to `/etc/dhcpcd`:

```
denyinterfaces wlan0
```

Comment: Welcome! This should rather be a comment on the original question, unless you'd like to expand on your answer?